# Why is “<br />” showing up in my <p> and not making a new line?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

When I add `<br />` to a `<p>`  in HTML, it doesn’t make a new line but shows `“<br />”`.

Here’s any example of what it shows:

```
Hello <br /> World
```

BTW I’m using [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com).
I have my HTML like this:

```
<p>{{content}}</p>
```

I’m expecting it to make a new line instead of put `“<br />”`

I’ve tried to use `<br>` but same problem.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`

```
<p>{{{content}}}</p>
```

For more details: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that already, but I guess not. BTW it worked

Answer (score 0):

By default, Handlebars escapes any HTML in the content you provide, so `<br />` becomes `&lt;br /&gt;` in the source, which then renders as <br />.

You can disable the escaping by using triple braces instead of the usual double braces.

See the documentation about this at https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping